# How to connect Snowflake to a Redshift table?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, aws-glue, snowflake-schema

I have been granted read access credentials to a redshift schema with several tables. This data will remain in Redshift and there are no migration plans to Snowflake. The data is weekly updated. What I would like to do is use this credentials to create a connection to this data from Snowflake so that I can query it from there. How should it do it? I see no option in the UI top bar.

I have the usual connection info (host, port, service name, user, password).

[image]

Comment: Hi - what makes you think you can expose/connect to a Redshift table in Snowflake?

Comment: seems federated querying from snowflake to redshift is not possible - thought it might have been possible

Comment: If your data is file-based and sitting in, for example, an S3 bucket then in Snowflake you can create an External Table that can read the data and make it available within Snowflake - but apart from that you have to physically import the data into Snowflake to use it

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way something like this is possible without an ETL tool or python etc is to query the redshift tables and dump the results into an s3 bucket which you can connect into Snowflake